# Parse text file with PHP

Tags: php, parsing, file-io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help me parse this file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917666/help-me-parse-this-file-with-php)

I need to extract some text from a text file.suppose there is a text file in `http://site.com/a.txt`

And the contents of that file is like this:

```
var $name= 'name1';
var $age= 'age2';
var $phone= 'phonenumber';
var $a= 'asd';
var $district= 'district23';
```

How can I get the values of this text file (name1,age2,phonenumber,asd,district) in separate echo.

Comment: is it necessary to have text file ? you can put this variables into php file and then include this file into another file and then you can echo variable

Comment: Did you try anything? We don't just give answers. We help you learn.

Comment: Please can you answer these three questions to help me help you - Does the contents of the file have to be like this? Is the file on the same domain as your page? Can you make this file a PHP file?

Comment: @GBD beat me to asking the questions! +1 to you!

Comment: Tell us more about this text file. Did you make it, must it be a text file, etc?

Comment: why is php code in a text file?

Comment: If it must be in a text file, and that file is trusted, you could use eval() and then echo the variables, but not sure how that would be.

Comment: If a.txt begins with php tag <? and closed with ?>, you can directly include that a.txt and echo those variables.

Comment: -1 for [posting your question again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513912/need-help-in-php) instead of editing this one with more information, and for the terrible all-caps title in said other question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Organize the content of your text file like this : name1,age2,phonenumber,asd,district

And do this :

```
// Get the content of your file
$content = file_get_contents('a.text');
// Set your values with this
list($name, $age, $phone, $a, $district) = explode(',', $content);

// Then feel free to echo wathever you want
echo 'Name ' . $name;
```

Comment: i tried this:

<?
$file='http://localhost/php/1.txt';
$q = @file_get_contents($file);
list($host, $user) = explode(',', $content);
echo $host;
 ?>

But it comes with an error.

Notice: Undefined variable: content in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\test.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\test.php on line 8

Comment: Replace explode(',', $content); by explode(',', $q);

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`file`](http://ir.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function to read the file into an array. Then loop through the array and each line in the file will be another element in the array. So make sure your file has line-breasks between the data.

Of course the best would be to have ready PHP code in a .php file which would then be included with the `include` function.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a class to encapsulate your data...

So imagine having a file called "person.php" that looks like this...

```
class Person
{
    public $Name;
    public $Age;
    public $Phone;
    public $A;
    public $District;
}
```

You can then use the person class as a container.

```
include_once('person.php');

$person = new Person();
$person->Name = 'John Doe';
$person->Age = 52;
$person->Phone= '+441234 567 890';
$person->A = 'asd';
$person->District = 'District23';
```

Please note that "Age" is volatile (i.e. if the object lives for too long, the age will wrong!) You could avoid this by storing date of birth and then having a getAge() function on the Person object that gives you the correct age at any point in time.

The Person class is a plain PHP object, but you could add functions that add behaviour that relates to the concept of a Person, so the getAge() function would live on the Person class.

Finally, you could then store the object wherever you like using PHP's [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) functions. The stored string that represents your object would look like this:

```
O:6:"Person":5:{
    s:4:"Name";s:8:"John Doe";
    s:3:"Age";i:52;
    s:5:"Phone";s:15:"+441234 567 890";
    s:1:"A";s:3:"asd";
    s:8:"District";s:10:"District23";
}
```

And here is how you serialize the `$person` to look like this:

```
$serializedPerson = serialize($person);
echo $serializedPerson;
```

And converting from a string back to a Person is easy too:

```
$serializedPerson = 'O:6:"Person":5:{s:4:"Name";s:8:"John Doe";s:3:"Age";i:52;s:5:"Phone";s:15:"+441234 567 890";s:1:"A";s:3:"asd";s:8:"District";s:10:"District23";}';

$newPerson = unserialize($serializedPerson);

echo $newPerson->Name;
```

**Summary**

So if you stored you data in this serialized format, it is really easy to convert it directly into a PHP object that you can use without manually parsing the strings. You could store the string in a text file if you wanted - or a data store.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array and encode it: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

Rather than giving you the solution code I'm going to break this down into steps for you.

0) write the file in a machine readable format, e.g. name,age,phonenumber

1) Read from the file line by line

2) Break each line up according to the separator you used e.g. ","

3) Read in values into variables

4) Echo out

If you're stuck on something more specific, let us know.